# How to replace string and upload with php

Tags: php

i want upload image from base64 png and rename it with different image type.

```
if ($img) { 
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . $name . = str_replace("image/", ".", $type); 
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) it has built in base64 [data uri](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php) [protocol wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php):

```
if ($img) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($img); // $img = 'data:image/png;base64,....'
    // setting $file name etc.
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $contents);
}
```